# 301 Redirect with Regular Expressions

Tags: wordpress, redirect, migration, permalinks

Couldn't find an answer to this and thought it might be a quick answer.

My company, a local news site, is working on migrating to WordPress from a proprietary CMS. Part of the challenge is we are restructuring URLs. I will be utilizing 301 redirects but my issue is as follows:

Example Page name: Story Name: is "this"
Example Old CMS Page URL: /story-name--is--this-/
New CMS Page URL: /news/2012/09/12/story-name-is-this/

The old CMS turned special characters and spaces into hyphens. WordPress will be configured to instead ignore special characters and simply turn spaces into hyphens. Additionally, the old CMS did not include the date in the URL, and I'm not sure the best route to take regarding adding the date.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're either going to have to write a script that takes all of your old links, does a lookup in your database to transform it into the new link, and redirect the browser to the new link. Or you'll have to enumerate the entire mapping of old links -> new links and create a 301 redirect for each of them (in either your vhost/server config or in an htaccess file):

```
Redirect 301 /story-name--is--this-/ /news/2012/09/12/story-name-is-this/
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what is your real question? I am also not sure what Regular expressions have to do with the problem.

There is no information about what your old CMS is capable of, assuming that you can  intercept the calls to old articles when they are accessed via the browser, but before they are rendered you can form and send the redirect back to the browser dynamically generating the url using the programming mechanisms available in your proprietary CMS.

Again, assuming you have access to Java:

A. When generating the redirect URL you can access the article's date and form the 
2012/09/12 from the date, you can use SimpleDateFormatter to format Dates into a string representation like YYYY/MM/DD.

 B. You can use similar approach with the titles and replace the list of special characters in the title string with empty spaces. For example Apache StringUtils library can let you specify a set of characters to look for and if any are found they will be replaced with the target character.

 C. You concatenate the output of A and B to create the target redirect URL and send it back to the browser instead of the article itself.